# How to open/link external files inside a HTML-designed QuickLook plugin without using the <src> attribute?

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, src, quicklook

After my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216194/how-to-develop-create-a-gui-for-a-quicklook-plugin), it seems that I gotta definitely deal with the fact that I have to use HTML in order to design interactive GUIs...but now the problem is another one: I know that for security reasons is not possible (unlike on Xcode 4.2 with OSX 10.6.8) to open/link anymore files from external directories using the `<src>` attribute, and I was wondering if there might be other ways to achieve that goal.

On [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/quicklook_programming_guide/Articles/QLDynamicGeneration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005020-CH15-SW2) ("Generating Enriched HTML" paragraph) is shown a portion of code that includes a CSS file as a MIME attachment: do you recon that it could be possible to obtain the same result with a different type of file (such a JS library or an image/video/audio)?

Here's some code from my project:

```
OSStatus GeneratePreviewForURL(void *thisInterface, QLPreviewRequestRef preview, CFURLRef url, CFStringRef contentTypeUTI, CFDictionaryRef options)
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        if (QLPreviewRequestIsCancelled(preview)) return noErr;

        NSMutableString *html=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *props;

        props=@{
            (__bridge NSString *)kQLPreviewPropertyTextEncodingNameKey:@"UTF-8",
            (__bridge NSString *)kQLPreviewPropertyMIMETypeKey:@"text/html",
            };

        [html appendString:@"<html>"];
        [html appendString:@"<head>"];
        [html appendString:@"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"JQuery.js\">"];
        [html appendString:@"</script>"];
        [html appendString:@"<script>"];
        //...
        [html appendString:@"</script>"];
        [html appendString:@"</head>"];
        [html appendString:@"<body>"];
        //...
        [html appendString:@"</body>"];
        [html appendString:@"</html>"];

        QLPreviewRequestSetDataRepresentation(preview,(CFDataRef)[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],kUTTypeHTML,(CFDictionaryRef)props);
    }

    return noErr;
}
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all kinds of files (within the limits of how Quick Look sandboxes WebKit) can be attached using the `cid:` scheme. This is just a way to tell WebKit how to locate the data corresponding to a resource, so it can be used for all kinds of resources.

In your case, load `JQuery.js` in a `NSData` object, write `src=\"cid:JQuery.js\"` and add this to your props object for the `kQLPreviewPropertyAttachmentsKey`

```
@{
  @"JQuery.js" : @{ 
             (__bridge NSString *)kQLPreviewPropertyMIMETypeKey : @"text/javascript",
             (__bridge NSString *)kQLPreviewPropertyAttachmentDataKey: dataContainingJQuery
  },
},
```

Comment: Thanks, Thomas for answering me...you've been very helpful! One last thing: if I don't want to look for the JS file inside a particular folder, what am I suppose to write into `dataWithContentsOfFile`? The tilde before the slash seems not working at all.

Comment: Store the JS file in your generator's bundle and use the same code as on Apple's sample :     Use `+[NSBundle bundleForClass:]` to locate your bundle, then `-[bundle URLForResource:withExtension:]` to locate the JS and load it with `+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]`

Comment: I actually wrote this question because I knew that I could find a solution trying to replicate the Apple's sample code, but I kept having issues with its fake class `HTMLPreviewBuilder`: what am I supposed to substitute it with?

Comment: Any class that's part of the code that gets compiled in your bundle. It's just a way to locate the right bundle.